# Can't use robotframework-androidlibrary

Tags: fedora, android-library, robotframework

I am using RIDE of robotframework in fedora.Now I installed robotframework-androidlibrary and calabash-android,but when I imported AndroidLibrary in RIDE,it's red.
What should I do?What should I install?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question "what should I do", the first thing I recommend is to try running your test from the command line without using RIDE. This will tell you whether it's a problem unique to RIDE, or if RIDE is obscuring an error that is being generated by the framwork.

When you run your test from the command line you should see an error message that will give you a clue as to why the library couldn't be loaded. Maybe you have a typo in the name, or maybe there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below link for installation of Robotframework Android library which sits on top of Calabash Android framework.

http://www.8bitavenue.com/2012/12/robotframework-android-automation/